# Unable to insert into MySQL database with php

Tags: php, mysql

In this Insert function where I have to insert a book into the database. The author is already existed in the database and I am trying insert a book that is written by the same author. What I am trying to achieve is to prevent user from entering the already existing author that would make duplicate data. When I get to the record the changelog with BookID but I get the a MySQL error where it says

> "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'SELECT BookID from book WHERE BookID = 102' for column 'BookID' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\bookprojectdb\Model\bookInsertFunction.php on line 97".

```
function addBook2($existauthor, $bt, $ot, $yop, $genre, $sold, $lan, $cip, $bp, $ps, $userID){
global $conn;
try {
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    //Author Data already exist

    //Book Data
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO book(BookTitle, OriginalTitle, YearofPublication, Genre, 
    MillionsSold, LanguageWritten, CoverImagePath, AuthorID)
    VALUES(:bt, :ot, :yop, :genre, :sold, :lan, :cip, :authorid);");
    $stmt->bindValue(':bt', $bt);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ot', $ot);
    $stmt->bindValue(':yop', $yop);
    $stmt->bindValue(':genre', $genre);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sold', $sold);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lan', $lan);
    $stmt->bindValue(':cip', $cip);
    $stmt->bindValue(':authorid',$existauthor);
    $stmt->execute();

    //BookPlot Data
    $lastbookID = $conn->lastInsertID();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bookplot(Plot, PlotSource, BookID) 
    VALUES(:bp, :ps, :bookid);");
    $stmt->bindValue(':bp', $bp);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ps', $ps);
    $stmt->bindValue(':bookid', $lastbookID);
    $stmt->execute();

    //Changelog Date Create Insert. This inserts date created, bookid and userid.
    $datecreated = (date('y-m-d h:m:s'));
    $bookID = "SELECT BookID from book WHERE BookID = $lastbookID";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO changelog(DateCreated, BookID, UserID)
    VALUES(:datecreated, :bookid, :userid);");
    $stmt->bindValue(':datecreated', $datecreated);
    $stmt->bindValue(':bookid', $bookID);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userID);
    $stmt->execute();
    //commit 
    $conn->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
}
}
```

$existauthor

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Surname, AuthorID FROM author WHERE Name = :name AND Surname = :surname");
$query->bindValue(':name', $name);
$query->bindValue(':surname', $surname);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();

 if($query->rowCount() < 1){ //if author doesn't exists
    addBook($name, $surname, $nationality, $yob, $yod, 
    $bt, $ot, $yop, $genre, $sold, $lan, $cip, $bp, $ps, $userID);
    header('location:../View/Pages/adminView.php'); 
}else {
    //if author exists
    $existauthor = $row['AuthorID'];
    addBook2($existauthor,$bt, $ot, $yop, $genre, $sold, $lan, $cip, $bp, $ps, $userID);
    header('location:../View/Pages/adminView.php'); 
}
```

I thought that by using "lastinsertID();", it would have recorded ID of recently created book. Please Help !

Comment: Why are you not checking for errors upon execution of your queries?

Comment: You are assigning a _string value_, `$bookID = "SELECT BookID from book WHERE BookID = $lastbookID";`, and then you try to use that and bind it to the parameter with `$stmt->bindValue(':bookid', $bookID);` - of course that does not work.

Comment: What is `$lastauthorID`? `rowCount()` should be called on the statement, i.e. `query`.

Comment: And even if you actually executed that query, what would be the point of it? `SELECT BookID from book WHERE BookID = $lastbookID` - if this returns any record(s), then `BookID` will obviously have the value of `$lastbookID` in those again.

Comment: @Booboo it wasn't meant to be lastAuthorID. it was supposed to be query that I select from the database. I will edit the question

Comment: @CBroe the purpose is to insert the bookid of the recently inserted book into the changelog. I tried to put  $lastbookID = $conn->lastInsertID(); into the changelog part too but it says "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails "

Comment: I was talking about the SELECT query you assigned to `$bookID`. That does not have any actual, meaningful purpose - you would be querying the same value from the database, that you already _have_ in the variable `$lastbookID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'SELECT BookID from book WHERE BookID = 102'` - that is an incorrect integer value indeed.

You have this value assigned to a variable:

```
$bookID = "SELECT BookID from book WHERE BookID = $lastbookID";
```

and then you're trying to bind it in place of an integer:

```
    $stmt->bindValue(':bookid', $bookID);
```

Comment: I did this because when I tried putting $lastbookID = $conn->lastinsertID(); but it gives a different error instead: "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails".

Comment: Because `lastInsertID();` returns the id generated by the most recent insert (i.e. `INSERT INTO bookplot`...). You probably want to use `$lastbookID` you had obtained earlier

Comment: I am fully aware of that. That's why I tried the method that was written in the question. I am wondering how can I insert the bookID from lastinsertID();. But it was used for bookplot.

Comment: lastInsertID() is not a bookID, since last insert was into "bookplot" (whatever primary key there. bookplot_id?). You just need to use `$lastbookID` which you already have. I.e. `$stmt->bindValue(':bookid', $lastbookID);`. That is.

Comment: I took your advice and work it and it was a success. Thank you so much ! This is one of my first project as a novice in PHP and MySQL. The purpose of the function was too prevent user from re-entering the details of the same author that already exist in the database. Once again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the help you need:

```
if(!$stmt->execute()) echo $stmt->error;
```

You ALWAYS should expect errors, and have a workaround, but first you need to check for `errors`